# Panoramio Data API Not Returning Photos Data

Tags: api, panoramio

I tried to get JSON [on this URL](http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=public&from=0&to=1&minx=-180&miny=-85&maxx=-175&maxy=-80&size=original) and it returns `count = 4` but no photos array returned? No matter what values `from` and `to` are set.

If count is `4` then `from` can be at most `3` right? (0, 1, 2, 3 that's 4 photos)
Or how does this work? Why didn't it return photos?

Also, sort of the same problem: for one area I got `count = 662` but it won't return photos array if I set `from` greater than `56`.